# Regex to get all the field names from a select query

Tags: regex

I am not that good with regex, so please don't mind if its too simple.

I have an SQL query that is stored as a raw string in some file.

```
SELECT "table_name"."prop_id",
"table_name"."some_other_id",
"table_name"."blueprint_id",
COUNT("table_name"."id") AS "total_count",
COUNT("table_name"."id") FILTER (WHERE "table_name"."is_primary" = true) AS "some_count",
COUNT("table_name"."id") FILTER (WHERE "table_name"."is_primary" = false) AS "extra_count"
FROM table_name
```

Now i want to get all the substrings (name of output columns) from this query usng a regex (preferably).

So my output should be a list of  `["prop_id", 'some_other_id', 'blueprint_id', 'total_count', 'some_count', 'extra_count']`

**What i tried:**

I am not so good with regex but i have made this regex

```
/SELECT[\s\S]*[AS](.*),[\s\S]*FROM/g
```

it does not give the desired result

Comment: Consider using a proper parser instead.

Comment: do you mean doing it programatically by splitting on `,`  and something like that  ?

Comment: regexes may backfire if the query is compex and dynamic. [parser](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is always the best choice for HTMLs and your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solving it with grep and sed, it could look like this:

```
>>> cat sql.txt | grep -Eo '"\w+",?$' | sed 's/[",]//g'
prop_id
some_other_id
blueprint_id
total_count
some_count
extra_count
```

In Python it would be (given, that your query is stored to *sql*):

```
>>> re.findall(r'.*"(.*)"', sql)
['prop_id', 'some_other_id', 'blueprint_id', 'total_count', 'some_count', 'extra_count']
```

Comment: Thanks,! that helps a lot... but is there a way to filter the python expression to just look between the select & FROM clase, as some queries may have JOINS and where clause which will alos map to the regular expression

Comment: You mean between the beginning SELECT and a FROM?
Then you could do the following before the regex: `sql = sql[sql.index("SELECT"):sql.index("FROM")]`, given that the SQL commands are stored in a string called *sql*